# error "unable to copy file because it is being used by another process

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010, forms

I use windowsform application using C# language, I have many forms, and when I want to traverse from one to another, I use **this.Hide();**

When I use this method, I receive the shown error,

I know that the solution is to end process using windows task manager, But the question is that **Is there any way I can use travel between forms without leading to this error?**

```
 Error  9   Unable to copy file "obj\x86\Debug\WindowsFormsApplication1.exe" to "bin\Debug\WindowsFormsApplication1.exe". The process cannot access the file 'bin\Debug\WindowsFormsApplication1.exe' because it is being used by another process.  C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Common.targets  2868
```

Comment: When does this happen? When you recompile?

Comment: That's a compilation/file system issue, it has nothing to do with your code.

Comment: I guess you're hiding even the main form and trying to re run your app from another VS instance, why don't you just close the froms?

Comment: @VahidND, yeah I am hiding the main form, when I close the form it does not go away, I do not know why, only Hide function resolves the issue

Comment: How do you start your main form? Are you using the default method for starting winform programs? I mean Application.Run(new FormMain())

Comment: yeah I use this method

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Although you `Hide()` your forms, they still remain as a part of the process. If you don't close every form properly, the process will remain running and you cannot recompile your project and eventually you will have to kill your process using the taskmanager.
Visual Studio tries to rewrite your executable and if the executable runs as a process, Windows will refuse to write to your .exe.

Comment: as you say, if after hiding, I close all the forms, will this error be gone ?

Answer (score 13):

Easy going solution is to add some code in Project Properties..

Just go to Project tab and select project properties..
From there select Build Events tab.
And in Pre-build event Command line add the following code..

```
   if exist "$(TargetPath).locked" del "$(TargetPath).locked"
   if not exist "$(TargetPath).locked" move "$(TargetPath)" "$(TargetPath).locked"
```

Comment: I just used this in VS2017 because my Xamarin project kept failing like the OP's was. It worked for me too. Thanks.

Comment: Ok. I spoke too soon. Now it errored saying exited with code 1. Real helpful error message Microsoft. Sigh.

Answer (score 6):

Just delete the `.exe` file in the `bin` folder: `bin\Debug\WindowsFormsApplication1.exe`

Don't worry, the build will create a new one.

Comment: Thanks! I was not able to delete files/folder under bin as it was throwing error as 'file is being used by another program'. I renamed the project.exe running and tried building and that resolved this error for me.

Answer (score 3):

I believe this is happen while you compiling the application or you start debugging the application.

This may be due to.

1. While you stop the debug in VS, the process may not be stopped.
2. May be you just executed the application, by double clicking it.
3. Might be some issues due to permission. If you are using source control, some folders may be treated as read only while downloading the project. So you need to edit that manually.
4. Make sure that you used Application.Exit() to exit from all the process.
   http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.exit.aspx

Comment: actually when I hide the form, this error appears! what is the alternative coding?

Comment: how many forms you have ?  whether you hides all forms ?. show the code snippet

Comment: There are lots of forms, only one is shown below :

Class1 newclass = new Class1();
this.Hide();
newclass.Show();

Comment: when the error occurs. please share the steps in a high level mannae

Answer (score 3):

I finally how fix it. Why we can't continue debug after the first debug because the first debug exe still running. So that, after first debug, you need to go to Task Manager -> Process Tab -> [your project name exe] end the exe process.

Answer (score 1):

close visual studio
in windows 7
click Shift + Ctrl + esc
in Tab processes
find process like the name of your project and end it.

Answer (score 1):

If you can`t delete the .exe file try search the process of your program in task manager

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix it by deleting the suo file (hidden solution file).

Answer (score 0):

Simple method is to delete the .exe file from the project directory folder and build the project again. this will create new exe file and problem will solve.